Macbook Pro graphics problem
I had 23.10 installed on an old Macbook Pro 15 2015 model (i7, 16Gb) - everything was fine until I tried upgrading to 24.04 pretty soon after the release date. The upgrade didn't work well - graphics issues - so I went back to 23.10.
I've now done a clean install of 24.04 and have weird graphics issues. The dock renders fine, but not the desktop (most of it is a white box). Also render problems with terminal etc. but not Ubuntu 'settings' app. I'm guessing driver issue but my Google searches haven't come up with anything relevant i.e. less than 5 years old.
Any wisdom would be appreciated.

I faced same issue.
This duplicate post (link at bottom) solves the problem for me. The post author figured out disabling igx on intel_iommu solves this issue. Adding that original fix here.

looking at kernel logs (sudo dmesg) I found a number of errors reading:
... DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 3 ... DMAR: [DMA Read]
Request device ... non-zero reserved fields in PTE
I found posts suggesting to add intel_iommu=igfx_off to the GRUB
config in case of DMA errors, and that seems to have done the trick.
I'll call it a victory even if I didn't get down to the root cause of
this.
For reference, the full fix is:

 sudo nano /etc/default/grub
 
 Add intel_iommu=igfx_off to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT list 
 
 sudo update-grub

Large white area on screen on MacBook Pro 2015 laptop running Ubuntu 24.04
